# Access two elements simultaneously in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have some weirdly formatted HTML files which I have to parse.

This is my Ruby code:

```
File.open('2.html', 'r:utf-8') do |f| 
    @parsed = Nokogiri::HTML(f, nil, 'windows-1251')
    puts @parsed.xpath('//span[@id="f5"]//div[@id="f5"]').inner_text
end
```

I want to parse a file containing:

```
<span style="position:absolute;top:156pt;left:24pt" id=f6>36.4.1.1. варенье, джемы, конфитюры, сиропы</span>
<div style="position:absolute;top:167.6pt;left:24.7pt;width:709.0;height:31.5;padding-top:23.8;font:0pt Arial;border-width:1.4; border-style:solid;border-color:#000000;"><table></table></div>
<span style="position:absolute;top:171pt;left:28pt" id=f5>003874</span>
<div style="position:absolute;top:171pt;left:99pt" id=f5>ВАРЕНЬЕ &quot;ЭКОПРОДУКТ&quot; ЧЕРНАЯ СМОРОДИНА</div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:180pt;left:99pt" id=f5>325гр.  </div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:167.6pt;left:95.8pt;width:2.8;height:31.5;padding-top:23.8;font:0pt Arial;border-width:0 0 0 1.4; border-style:solid;border-color:#000000;"><table></table></div>
```

I need to select either `<div>` or `<span>` with `id==5`. With my current XPath selector it's not possible. If I remove `//span[@id="f5"]`, for example, then the divs are selected correctly. I can output them one after another:

```
puts @parsed.xpath('//div[@id="f5"]').inner_text
puts @parsed.xpath('//span[@id="f5"]').inner_text
```

but then the order would be a complete mess. The parsed `span` have to be directly underneath the `div` from the original file.

Am I missing some basics? I haven't found anything on the web regarding parallel parsing of two elements. Most posts are concerned with parsing two classes of a div for example, but not two different elements at a time.

Comment: I think you're misusing "parallel". It sounds like you want to locate two at a time, as a group. Also, you say `id==5` but your selectors search for `f5`. While it might seem to be picking nits, programming is exacting, and the description in the question needs to be also. It's confusing to people trying to help when the question isn't consistent, which slows and/or discourages answerers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you can use the following XPath :

```
//*[self::div or self::span][@id="f5"]
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/021dfcf4b37e45645bb776a9a750e60e)</kbd>**

The XPath above will find element named either `div` or `span` that have `id` attribute value equals `"f5"`

**output :**

```
<span id="f5" style="position:absolute;top:171pt;left:28pt">003874</span>

<div id="f5" style="position:absolute;top:171pt;left:99pt">ВАРЕНЬЕ "ЭКОПРОДУКТ" ЧЕРНАЯ СМОРОДИНА</div>

<div id="f5" style="position:absolute;top:180pt;left:99pt">325гр.</div>
```